# docx4j : "No suitable JAXB implementation available" runtime error Java 1.5

Tags: java, jaxb, docx4j

I am using docx4j to parse docx file.
I downloaded all JARs from docx4j site [docx4j downloads](http://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html).

When I used it in code, it gives runtime error at very first line of code: -

```
WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(new File("Global_OPO_Profile_EN.docx")));
```

Exception is:

```
INFO org.docx4j.utils.Log4jConfigurator .configure line 45 - Since your log4j configuration (if any) was not found, docx4j has configured log4j automatically.
ERROR org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 64 - PANIC! No suitable JAXB implementation available
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to locate jaxb.properties for package org.docx4j.relationships
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.searchcontextPath(ContextFinder.java:205)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:149)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:281)
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:47)
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:56)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:658)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
    at com.atos.docx4jtest.Docx4iTest.main(Docx4iTest.java:15)
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 76 - loading Context jc
ERROR org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 102 - Cannot initialize context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to locate jaxb.properties for package org.docx4j.wml
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.searchcontextPath(ContextFinder.java:205)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:149)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:281)
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:77)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:658)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
    at com.atos.docx4jtest.Docx4iTest.main(Docx4iTest.java:15)
ERROR org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager .parseContentTypesFile line 690 - java.lang.NullPointerException
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:691)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
    at com.atos.docx4jtest.Docx4iTest.main(Docx4iTest.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:658)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 1.5 does not include JAXB, so you need to download the JAXB reference implementation, and add it to your class path.

Comment: Hello Jason, Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me where to download exact implementation that's needed with JDK1.5?

Comment: It's on java.net somewhere I think, Google should be able to tell you where exactly.

Comment: I went through [jaxb.java.net](http://jaxb.java.net/) and tried downloading JAXB 2.2.6, but it seems its for JDK6 so it gives UnsupportedClassVersion exception when used. Also, there is big list of versions present but when I download it, I just get a Main.class file along with a META-INF folder.

Comment: [This JIRA comment](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-890?focusedCommentId=342373&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_342373) suggests that [2.2.4](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/) is the last version that works on Java 5.